# Obtaining form input from EJS file in .js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new to Javscript programming and using NodeJs. I am attempting to create a login/register page using NodeJS and Express to authenticate user information submitted on the login and register pages with the Firebase backend.

User inputs their information on the form constructed in the register.ejs file. I use document.getElementByID to obtain the user's inputs and store them in variables (txtEmail/txtPassword) for example. I use an eventListenter wait for a user to submit the the form on btnRegister and pass the contents of txtEmail and txtPassword into variables password and email, which are then passed into auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword to create user on Firebase backend.

I am having issues passing the user's inputs on the register page into btnRegister. In particular, I receive the following error message for txtEmail, txtPassword:

> ```
> const txtEmail = document.getElementById('email');
>                        ^
>
> ReferenceError: document is not defined
> ```

```
register.ejs:

<div class="row mt-5">
        <div class="col-md-6 m-auto">
          <div class="card card-body">
            <h1 class="text-center mb-3">
              <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i> Register
            </h1>
            <% include ./partials/messages %>
            <form action="/users/register" method="POST">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input
                  type="name"
                  id="name"
                  name="name"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Enter Name"
                  value="<%= typeof name != 'undefined' ? name : '' %>"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input
                  type="email"
                  id="email"
                  name="email"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Enter Email"
                  value="<%= typeof email != 'undefined' ? email : '' %>"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input
                  type="password"
                  id="password"
                  name="password"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Create Password"
                  value="<%= typeof password != 'undefined' ? password : '' %>"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password2">Confirm Password</label>
                <input
                  type="password"
                  id="password2"
                  name="password2"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Confirm Password"
                  value="<%= typeof password2 != 'undefined' ? password2 : '' %>"
                />
              </div>
              <button id="btnRegister" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                Register
              </button>
            </form>
            <p class="lead mt-4">Have An Account? <a href="/users/login">Login</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>

<script src="/routes/users.js"></script>

users.js:

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');


  //Get Elements
  const txtEmail = document.getElementById('email');
  const txtPassword = document.getElementById('password');
  const btnRegister = document.getElementById('btnRegister');

//User model
const User = require('../models/user')

//Login page
router.get('/login', (req, res) => res.render('login'));

//Register page
router.get('/register', (req, res) => res.render('register'));

// Register
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password, password2 } = req.body;
    const promise = (email, password, password2);
    let errors = [];

    if (!name || !email || !password || !password2) {
      errors.push({ msg: 'Please enter all fields' });
    }

    if (password != password2) {
      errors.push({ msg: 'Passwords do not match' });
    }

    if (password.length < 6) {
      errors.push({ msg: 'Password must be at least 6 characters' });
    }

    if (errors.length > 0) {
      res.render('register', {
        errors,
        name,
        email,
        password,
        password2
      });
    } else 
        {
          btnRegister.attachEvent('onclick', e => {
            const email = txtEmail.value;
            const password = txtPassword.value;
            const auth = firebase.auth();
            const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
            promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
          });

        }
});


module.exports = router;


app.js 

const express = require('express');
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
//const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const firebase = require('firebase');

const app = express();

//DB config
//const db = require('./config/keys').MongoURI;

//Connect to Mongo
//mongoose.connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true})
    .then(() => console.log('MongooseDB Connected...'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

//Firebase config
var config = {
        apiKey: "********"
        authDomain: "*****",
        databaseURL: "*****",
        projectId: "*****",
        storageBucket: "******,
        messagingSenderId: "******",
        appId: "*******"
};
//Connect to Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(config);

//EJS
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//Bodyparser
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//Routes
app.use('/', require('./routes/index.js'));
app.use('/users', require('./routes/users.js'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));

layout.ejs

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="https://bootswatch.com/4/materia/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/420440220d.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/6.3.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/6.3.4/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/6.3.4/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="/routes/users.js"></script>
</body>

    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <%- body %>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Users submits their information into the registration form, information is stored into variables with are based into Firebase authentication to create user.